# Interpreting given paragraph and turning it into Prolog code

Tags: prolog

Isaac and Albert were excitedly describing the result of the Third Annual International Science
Fair Extravaganza in Sweden. There were three contestants, Louis, Rene, and Johannes. Isaac reported
that Louis won the fair, while Rene came in second. Albert, on the other hand, reported that Johannes
won the fair, while Louis came in second.

In fact, neither Isaac nor Albert had given a correct report of the results of the science fair. Each of them had given one correct statement and one false statement. What was the actual placing of the three contestants? Please base your solution to a Prolog program.

Well, i am beginner at prolog and i want  to interpret such paragraphs into prolog code but i am not sure how to approach to this. Can you lead me about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by recording the statements of Isaac and Albert. 1 and 2 are used to identify the statements ("the first statement of Isaac..."), each list represents the participants in their order.

```
isaac(1,[louis,_,_]).
isaac(2,[_,rene,_]).
albert(1,[johannes,_,_]).
albert(2,[_,louis,_]).
```

Next we say who participated in the fair and that any answer should be a permutation of the three names. I'm working with SWI prolog, so `permutation` is a built-in predicate:

```
domain([louis,johannes,rene]).
valid(X):- domain(D), permutation(D,X).
```

Finally, we put everything together:

```
go(X) :- isaac(I,X), 
         albert(J,X), 
         valid(X), 
         \+ (isaac(K,X), dif(I,K)), 
         \+ (albert(L,X), dif(J,L)).
```

Two last lines ensure that *only one* claim of Isaac (Albert) is true.